# Creating user profile tables that are publicly accessible in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, model

I am having some trouble with my application when trying to create the user profiles. Here is the issue:

I am trying to create a view called userprofile.blade.php which will output any given users profile (based on id or username...doesn't really matter right now). Each profile page will show name, description, location, profile pic, and the given users posts. I used Laravel's Make:auth command to create the necessary authentication, customized the authentication forms, and then migrated all the columns I needed in my database.

My create and update methods work just fine (registering new users and updating their information). All the information is saved correctly in the database. However, I can only access it in my views with {{Auth::user()->}}. Whenever I try to use the Model in my Controller to access the data I need, it doesn't work. It seems to me as though I need to separate Laravel's default 'User' model with a custom model which I would call 'Account' or something along those lines.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Recipe;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  /**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => [
        'index', 'show'
    ]]);
}

public function index(){
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('user.userprofile')->with('user');
}
```

I only included the index method from my UserController to keep it simple. It breaks down and tells me that 'id' in $user = User::find($id); is an undefined variable. That tells me that it isn't accessing my database table.

My question is, should I create a new fresh model that isn't mixed up with authentication to handle all the user profile information? If so, how do I access my current database table 'users' from this new model?

Please let me know if I need to clarify things for you guys. I'm not very experienced and I understand if my question is fuzzy. Thanks so much for your time!! I really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: how many different users can access the profile? e.g Admin, Marketers, Account or all of them will just have one model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to developing with Laravel!

You're on the right track - you need to identify which user's profile you're viewing, retrieve it from the database, and pass it to the Blade view. You don't need a new model or anything, though! Just need to complete what you've started.

You should start by defining a [route parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters) in your route, that will capture the dynamic data you want from the URL. Let's use the numeric ID for now. If you want a URL that looks like `example.com/user/439`, your route should look something like `Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@index');`.

Once you have that, the `id` parameter will get passed to your controller's method. Define it as a method parameter, and it'll be usable: `public function index($id) { ... }`

I think you can take it from there. :)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer and helping me along the way! This was super helpful!! :)